# Regex not working to remove string/whatever

Tags: javascript

How can I remove this string from href and update it ?

Example Url:

```
"localhost:21088/WcfDataService1.svc/Clients?$top=20&$select=Name,Products/Name,ID,People/FirstName,Products/Price,People/LastName&$expand=People"
```

What I am trying:

```
var stringToRemove = "Products" + "/";
var url = $("#qUrl").attr("href");
url = url.replace('/(' + stringToRemove + '\/\w+,)/g', '');
$("#qUrl").attr("href", url);
```

What I want:

```
"localhost:21088/WcfDataService1.svc/Clients?$top=20&$select=Name,ID,People/FirstName,People/LastName&$expand=People"
```

**Update**

Please don't hard code

Comment: @KalpeshRajai What? `"str".replace(pattern/string, replacement)`...

Comment: @KalpeshRajai I think u are confused, please try a jsfiddle to prove your point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking to remove all `Products/...,` than RegEx is `/Products\/.*?,/g`

Take a note that RegExp is written *as is* - without surrounding it with quotes.

```js
var str = 'localhost:21088/WcfDataService1.svc/Clients?$top=20&$select=Name,Products/Name,ID,People/FirstName,Products/Price,People/LastName&$expand=People';

console.log(str.replace(/Products\/\w+,?/g, ''));

/**
 * Replace with variable string
 */

var key = 'Products'; // Come from external source, not hardcoded.
var pattern = new RegExp(key+'/\\w+,?', 'g'); // Without start and end delimiters!
console.log(str.replace(pattern, ''));
```

Comment: thank you, thing is I am getting "Products" as a string from somewhere else, can I use it and add "/" to it with above ?

Comment: It works fine +1, but I am having trouble e.g. when I have this Products/Price&$expand=People, it is also removing  &$expand=... part as well :(

Comment: @Mathematics Check now.

Answer (score 0):

```
 var stringToRemove = "Products" + "/";
 var url = $("#qUrl").attr("href");
url = url.replace(/Products\/Name,/g, '');
 $("#qUrl").attr("href", url);
```

Modify the replace call , use regex without quotes

Comment: In string there is also `Products/Price` that you do not replace.